# Trouble with stacking in ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists, z-index, css-position

I am having trouble with element stacking in a HTML page. I need to get **span** (class=**"class_span"**) to have a higher stacking order than **div** (class=**"class_div"**) with border. I have tried to change the z-index but with no luck. I know that I should not use absolute position, but the page is dependent on it, sorry. How can I accomplish this?

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="class_div">
        </div>
        <span class="class_span">
            <a href="google.com">google</a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS**:

```
.class_div{
    position: absolute; 
    border: 100px solid; 
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
}
.class_span{
    float: left;
}​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YMrLd/10/)

Comment: Just set `z-index:-1` of div class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the span so that you can apply `z-index` on it. Note that the `z-index` of your span must be higher than that of the `div` so that it appears above the `div`:

```
.class_div{
    position: absolute; 
    border: 100px solid; 
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.class_span{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}​
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YMrLd/17/)**

**Edit:**

As an alternative to `float: left`, you might consider using `position: absolute` and set `left` to `0px`:

```
.class_span{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}​
```

You may need to set the `top` as well, and it may also be necessary to set a parent element's `position` to `relative` so that the span can be positioned relative to that parent element.

Answer (score 1):

`position:absolute` will remove an element from the flow. You'll need to use `position` on `.class_span` too with a higher `z-index`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this.
http://jsfiddle.net/YMrLd/18/

The following CSS is there in the fiddle link.

```
.class_div{
    position: absolute; 
    border: 100px solid; 
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
}
.class_span{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}​
```

And let me know you need anything different.
Please attached a screenshot of your desired output if this doesn't help.

Comment: Please include code, not only a link. If JSFiddle has maintenance, is blocked or otherwise unreachable the OP or future users won't know what you've done and why you've done it.

Comment: I have added the CSS in question.